# Day.js - Get array of remaining months in year

Tags: javascript, dayjs

I want to get an array of the index of remaining months (0-index), not including current month, in a countdown, this year (or any date for the sake of it). I'm using `lodash` and `dayjs`, but I feel my code is a bit hard to understand.

Is there a more "dayjs" way to get what I want? I have not found more help in the doc's library or other threads with a similar problem here.

```
// All months - Current year's remaining months (0-index), we map in reverse until reaching 0
const yearRemainingMonths = map(range(11 - dayjs().month()), n => 11 - n)
// []

// Let's pretend we are in June, so we'd get
// [11, 10, 9, 8, 7]
```

Answer (score 1):

There's not much a cleaner way. In the end, you have to loop once or to store the predefined array.

#### Example 1 - with cached data

```
import dayjs from 'dayjs'

const months = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]
function remainingMonths(month) {
  return [...months].splice(month+1).reverse()
}

console.log(remainingMonths(dayjs().month())) // []
console.log(remainingMonths(5))  // june => [ 11,10,9,8,7,6]
console.log(remainingMonths(0))  // [11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]
```

#### Example 2 - with `for loop`

```
function remainingMonths(month) {
  const remaining = []
  for(let i = 11; i > month; i--) {
    remaining.push(i)
  }
  return remaining
}

console.log(remainingMonths(11)) // []
console.log(remainingMonths(5))  // june => [ 11,10,9,8,7,6]
console.log(remainingMonths(0))  // [11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]
```

Probably the `for` loop is a bit cleaner.